# Webpack UglifyJsPlugin not using passed options

Tags: webpack, uglifyjs

I'm currently trying to work out a few issues with our production builds with Webpack. Despite explicitly telling uglifyjs to not compress or mangle, my bundles are compressed and mangled. Any reason why Webpack/UglifyJS might disregard the options object I'm using?

**package.json script**

`NODE_ENV=production CONFIGS_PATH=$CONFIGS_PATH webpack -p --progress --config ./config/webpack/backend/production.babel.js`

**config/webpack/backend/production.babel.js**:

```
const production = {
    target: 'node',
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    node: {
        console: true,
        fs: 'empty'
    },
    entry: {
        server: `${rootPath}/src/server/server`,
    },
    output: {
        path: `${rootPath}/_dist/`,
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /react-icons\/(.)*(.js)$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                include: 'node_modules/react-icons'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['babel', 'strip-loader?strip[]=debug,strip[]=console.log'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        root: rootPath,
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.json'],
        alias: {
            app: `${sourcePath}/app`,
            actions: `${sourcePath}/app/actions`,
            components: `${sourcePath}/app/routes/common`,
            containers: `${sourcePath}/app/containers`,
            middleware: `${sourcePath}/app/middleware`,
            reducers: `${sourcePath}/app/reducers`,
            routes: `${sourcePath}/app/routes`,
            store: `${sourcePath}/app/store`,
            utils: `${sourcePath}/app/utils`,
            assets: `${sourcePath}/assets`,
            server: `${sourcePath}/serve`
        }
    },
    externals: [externals()],
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: false,
            mangle: false
        }),
        new ExtendedDefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
                APP_SETTINGS: settings,
                API_SETTINGS: apiSettings
            },
            __DEVELOPMENT__: false,
            __PRODUCTION__: true,
            __DEVTOOLS__: false,
            __TESTING__: false
        }),
    ],
};
```

I've also tested the removal of `-p` from my build script, but still end up with minified and mangled bundles.

Comment: Have the same issue